# ArrayList will not allow scanner input

Tags: java

I'm confused about something, again, in my code. I'm a beginner, but I still am familiar with the Scanner class. However, for a generic array, it bypasses the user input of a string. I want to understand why it's not being "collected" for the ArrayList:

```
public static void addingIngredients(){
    ArrayList<String> Ingredients = new ArrayList<String>();
    String addedIngredient = input.nextLine();
    Ingredients.add(addedIngredient);
    System.out.println(Ingredients +": Continue?" );
    System.out.println("1 (Yes) / 2 (No)");
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    switch (choice){
    case 1:
        addingIngredients();
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

The String "addedIngredient" is being skipped; This is what I'm receiving via console:

```
 Now Loading...
 What Ingredients are in this protein powder? 
 Begin Add?
 1 (Yes) / 2 (No)
 1
 []: Continue?
 1 (Yes) / 2 (No)
 1
[]: Continue?
1 (Yes) / 2 (No)
2
Test
```

Thank you in advance. P.S: Is there a more convenient way to write a loop to collect data from the user?

Comment: Please learn to respect the Java naming conventions. Variables start with a lowercase letter. Also, you should have a break in each of your cases, otherwise case2 is executed even if the user typed 1.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use recursion for this particular type of user input. Recursion tends to allocate stack space for each internal call, and once you exceed the dedicated stack space by the JVM, you will receive a stack overflow exception. In your case, this would hardly happen as you would need endless number of ingredients to enter. Still, this is a bad practice.

Comment: This I know, I just wasn't concern with the "minor" details...until I posted here! lol! I Apologize...

Comment: Will keep in mind, Ivaylo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

youre creating a new ArrayList with every call. you need to either use the same one of collect the results of each recursive call.

here's a simpler version you can start with:

```
ArrayList<> ingredients = ...
while (true) {
  //primpt for ingrediant, add to list
  if (endOfInput()) { //this is where you prompt for 1/2
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1. Another problem is that nextInt() doesn't consume the end of the line. So the next call to nextLine() returns an empty string.

Comment: Wow, that is a good point. So should I just create a return array?

Comment: @user130110 - i put some skeleton code in my answer. just fill in the missing parts

Comment: I've created a test method for collecting the input, but that time I simply couldn't think of a loop. Now I know to just ponder a bit more for the loop itself, thank you both!

Comment: I didn't notice the code you gave me, thank you, radai.